# to schedule java programs by taking program names from derby database

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

This is what I had done..

```
mgr.addAlarm(new AlarmEntry("ComplexCron2",new int[]{dtime,10,28}, new int[]{16}, new int[]{-1}, new int[]{-1}, new int[]{Calendar.TUESDAY}, -1, new AlarmListener() {
  public void handleAlarm(final AlarmEntry entry) {


      Addempnew.main(null);
    System.out.println("\u0007Cron complex2 (" + new Date() + ")");
  }
}));
```

here Addempnew.main(null) is a java program and I would like to schedule it. But instead of using the program name directly, I want to take it from database.

Comment: You tagged your question with quartz-scheduler. What's more to add?

Comment: here it is possible to schedule only  Addempnew.main(null);but i need to schedule any java files by taking their names from database

Answer (score 0):

You have to

```
// 1. Load class Addempnew:
Class cl=Class.forName("Addempnew");
//Exceptions may occur, catch them.

// 2. retrieve static method main(String[]) via reflection:
Method m=cl.getMethod("main", String[].class);

// 3. call retrieved method via reflection:
m.invoke(null, null);
```

All these steps are described elsewhere.